# Keeping already set GET parameter values after form submission

Tags: php

My URL currently has:

```
/add_products_flavour.php?pro_id=2
```

in it. However, the pro_id value gets lost after I submit my form. I want to keep returning to the same page and keep the value of pro_id to be able to submit the form multiple times.

The form:

```
 <form  name="flavour_form" method="post" action="add_products_flavour.php">
            <label class="add_products_field_label" for="flavour">Aroma:</label>
            <input class="w-input" data-name="flavour" id="flavour" maxlength="256" name="flavour" required="required" type="text">
            <input class="add_products_form_button w-button" type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Adauga">
            <?php insertFlavour()?>
        </form>

function insertFlavour(){

    global $connection;
    $pro_id=getProductID();

        if (isset($_POST['insert_post'])) {
            $flavour = $_POST['flavour'];

            $insert_flavour_query = "insert into flavour (name) values ('$flavour')";
            $run_insert_flavour = mysqli_query($connection, $insert_flavour_query);


            if($run_insert_flavour){
                echo"<script>alert('flavour added!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('add_products_flavour.php?pro_id=$pro_id','_self')</script>";
        }

    }

}

function getProductID(){
    if(isset($_GET['pro_id'])) {
        $pro_id = $_GET['pro_id'];
        return $pro_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you not use `header('Location: add_products_flavour.php?pro_id='.$pro_id.');` after submitting has completed. in PHP rather than jQuery

Comment: result is still /add_products_flavour.php?pro_id=

Comment: does it return the id correctly from your function? have you tried to echo this to make sure.

Comment: it returns nothing because the pro_id is gone

Comment: so why not get the pro id on onload of page and save it before you submit the form.

Comment: or get pro_id, make a check to see you have it and then process the form in the your function

Answer (score 0):

solved it by doing

```
 <?php  $pro_id = $_GET['pro_id'];
        echo "<form  name='flavour_form' method='post' action='add_products_flavour.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>";
            ?>
```